# Verifying signature of non-hashed data with Ruby OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, rsa, digital-signature

I have an RSA public key, some data and a signature of that data.  I need to verify the signature.  However, the signature is not of a digest of the data, but of the entire data.  (The data itself is only 16 bytes, so the signer doesn't bother to hash the data before signing it.)  I can verify the signature in C by specifying a NULL engine when initializing the context:

```
EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(verify_key, NULL);
```

However, I have been unable to find an equivalent in Ruby's OpenSSL::PKey::PKey verify method.  That method requires a Digest object, and there is no Digest that I can find that doesn't actually hash but just returns the data as-is.  I tried creating my own Digest subclass, but I don't believe that can work, since the underlying OpenSSL library won't know about the existence of a custom digest type.

Am I stuck, or is there a way to solve this problem given that I cannot modify the code run by the signer?

Comment: Does this use PKCS#1v1.5 padding without hashing(ugly but reasonably secure), or does it use no padding at all(probably totally broken)?

Comment: It uses PKCS#1v1.5 padding without hashing.

Comment: Have you tried to find a function like `public_decrypt`? It may work, as normally you should not encryption with a private key and decrypt with a public key. With a bit of luck it will accept the signature version of PKCS#1 padding (note that the padding used for encryption and signing is different in PKCS#1).

Comment: Of course - decrypting the signature with the public key and verifying that it matches the data works fine.  So far this is working fine with the standard PKCS#1 padding, but I'll do some more research to see if the differing encryption and signing paddings are a problem in practice.  Thanks.

Comment: After a decrypt and validation of the padding, all that is left is a (if possible, secure) compare. So that would replace the verification function pretty well. Most of the security is in the modular arithmetic and padding.

Comment: Should I make this an answer, or do you have additional requirements that haven't been met?

Comment: @owlstead or Wammer - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter...

[owlstead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/owlstead):

> Have you tried to find a function like `public_decrypt`? It may work, as normally you should not encryption with a private key and decrypt with a public key. With a bit of luck it will accept the signature version of PKCS#1 padding (note that the padding used for encryption and signing is different in PKCS#1).

[Wammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916473/wammer):

> Of course - decrypting the signature with the public key and verifying that it matches the data works fine. So far this is working fine with the standard PKCS#1 padding, but I'll do some more research to see if the differing encryption and signing paddings are a problem in practice. Thanks.

[owlstead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/owlstead):

> After a decrypt and validation of the padding, all that is left is a (if possible, secure) compare. So that would replace the verification function pretty well. Most of the security is in the modular arithmetic and padding.